# SSH command in Jenkins Pipeline repeats itself

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline where I run an ssh command in order to verify credentials that were previously entered. Here's the step:

```
node {
    sh '''
        set +x
        sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T $USER@$HOST
    '''
}
```

It works fine when the provided credentials are correct, however with incorrect password it automatically repeats itself 3 times. This behavior is exclusive to Jenkins, as I have tried running it with wrong credentials directly from terminal on Jenkins hosts and it executes only one time as expected.

I suspected that it could be due to the different interpreter that Jenkins might use to run commands, so I tried running it with `#!/bin/bash`, however it yielded no results. What could be the case for such behaviour? Does it have anything to do with `pseudo-tty` allocation?

Here's the output of the ssh command with `-vvv` (verbose) option:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Comment: Try checking that your variables are passed with `echo $PASS $USER@$HOST` before `ssh`. If not, you may want double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: They are passed, it's not an issue. The problem is with the fact that `ssh` command automatically makes 3 attempts to connect when the password is incorrect. This leads to user getting blocked on first try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by setting the `NumberOfPasswordPrompts` option to 1:

```
sshpass -p pass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -T user@host
```

From [ssh_config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) man page:

> NumberOfPasswordPrompts
>   Specifies the number of password prompts
>   before giving up. The argument to this keyword must be an integer. The
>   default is 3.

Apparently with `sshpass` it only prompts for password once when run interactively as opposed to scripted manner.